# Text doesn't appear in a EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know it's kinda stupid question, but I couldn't find an answer : I have started to learn making android application on an internet tutorial. But now I'm blocked, I have 2 EditText that I use to calculate something (it doesn't matter), my problem is that no text is written when I click any letter on my emulator. I found that the problem is really with this part of code :

```
private OnKeyListener modificationListener = new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Set a defaut text somewhere else, on another EditText
        result.setText(defaut);
        return true;
    }
};
```

I guessed I was supposed to call the super fonction, but when I try it tells me it's an error : `super.onKey(v, keyCode, event);`

Thanks!

Comment: Return false....it must solve it mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning false instead of true.

If you return true your are consuming the event and so it is not there any more for other listeners to act on it.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea more or less. If you return true the event is not passed to other possible listeners waiting for it. In this case, the EditText never receives the key that was pressed.